# Is there a way in Windows to change the default local folder copying scheme (for example, to change "- Copy" to "v1", "v2",...)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

For example, say I have the txt file `test.txt`. When I copy it in the same folder, I don't want:

```
test.txt
test - Copy.txt
test - Copy - Copy.txt
```

I have already found the NamingTemplates modification, which lets me change the above to

```
test.txt
test (2).txt
test (3).txt
```

But now, I am hoping to find a modification that, finally, lets me write the above as

```
test.txt
testv1.txt
testv2.txt
```

For versions 1, 2,...

Is this a possible change in Windows? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this help?   ....    https://winaero.com/how-to-change-file-copy-name-template-in-windows-11/   .... I have tons of files but do not need a naming template, so I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @John. I have already implemented this registry change. I was wondering if there is something different. I use a lot of MATLAB files, which don't run when there is parentheses in the name!